# MYSQL - Create View to query two like tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to like tables Order_Items and Order_Items_Archived which both tables are InnoDB. I would like to create a query that I can pull all the Items from both orders. I am pretty sure I would do this with a VIEW but I cant seem to find reference to just select all records that have the exact same column names and column types.

Example:

```
select sum(OrderItems_Amount)
from Order_Items_View
where OrderItems_OrderDate = '2017-10-01';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the `union all` operator:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW order_items_view AS
SELECT * FROM order_items
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM order_items_archived
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use a `union all` query.  I would be inclined to add the source.  List the columns that you want:

```
select col1, col2, col3, . . . , 0 as is_archive
from order_items
union all
selecct col1, col2, col3, . . ., 1
from order_items_archive;
```

You can put a `create view` statement before the query to turn it into a view.